# How to find a duplicate in List<string, int> and sum their values

Tags: c#, list, file, duplicates

I have a file where are two items a line. There is a name  and its
value . Some names a identical and I want my code to recognize duplicates and sum up their values
*example:

line 1: 3(number of lines(name value)

line 2: ABC 5

line 3: XYZ 8

line 4: ABC 3*
Thank you for all your answers.

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?  In the code you're writing, what isn't working as expected?

Comment: You should provide what have you tried so far.

Comment: Some hint, look at `Dictionary<string,int>` it may help.

Comment: @vc74 from question "Some names a identical and I want my code to recognize duplicates and sum up their values", so I think he need distinct list of strings and sum of values

Comment: Lists have only one generic type parameter. There cannot be a `List<string, int>`. Please show what you have done so far.

Comment: @Corak I was more thinking about a declarative (Linq) solution, but an iterative approach (like the answer below) also does the job

Comment: @vc74 - hah, didn't see the answer. Yes, LINQ makes life so much easier. but it seems like OP is learing the language and I feel like with an iterative approach it is easier to see exactly what happens at a relatively low level. If that is understood, higher levels of abstraction provide more powerful ways to describe what should happen.

Answer (score 2):

You need to break down the problem, You can use Dictionary to store the result.

**Step 1:** Read the file. You can use File.ReadLines for it.

**Step 2 :** Iterate over the lines, except the first time, and split them based on separator, which your case is whitespace

**Step 3 :** If the key (first part of string split in step 2) is already in the Dictionary, you need to sum the values. Else, create a new entry in dictionry.

The result can be stored in Dictionary. You need to ensure duplicates are summed up.

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(@"e:\sample.txt");
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string,int>();
foreach(var line in lines.Skip(1))
{
   var values = line.Split(new string[]{" "},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if(dictionary.TryGetValue(values[0],out var value))
    {
       dictionary[values[0]] = (value +=int.Parse(values[1]));
    }
    else
    {
      dictionary.Add(values[0], int.Parse(values[1]));
    }
}
```

**Sample Input**

```
3
ABC 5
XYZ 8
ABC 3
```

Sample Output

[image]

Comment: Why not simply `ReadLines`? it's a good fit here since you're enumerating only once. Also you could use `TryGet` to avoid using `ContainsKey` + the dic indexer.

Comment: @vc74 that's good suggestion. Thanks, have updated the answer.

Comment: *"I want my code to recognize duplicates and sum up their values"* - I think your answer misses an important requirement

Comment: @AnuViswan - `value +=int.Parse(values[1]);` won't change the actual value of `dictionary[values[0]]`.

Comment: Look at the input and your output. ABC should equal 8

Comment: @Jamiec @ vc...appologies, i forgot to change it when i changed to TryGet ...Idiot me, I have updated the answer now

Comment: Still think this is overkill using a dictionary!

Comment: @Jamiec I agree, but i kind of guessed OP is still learning, so better thought the solution needs to be as simple as it can be.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to enumerate your file with `ReadLines` and then use a bit of LINQ to group/aggregate to remove duplicates and sum the values

The first line is pretty irrelevant so you can simply `Skip` that one

```
var result = File.ReadLines(@"c:\pathto\yourfile.txt")
             .Skip(1)  // skip the first line
             .Select(line => line.Split(' ')) // Split on the space gving an array of 2 elements
             .GroupBy(x => x[0]) // group by the first element
             .Select(g => new {
                           Key = g.Key, 
                           Value = g.Sum(x => int.Parse(x[1]))
                          }); // select into an anonymous object
```

Demo: https://rextester.com/KSNI79479

(Note demo cannot use a file, but replicates the content of your file using an array)

Comment: +1 I think the OP might want you to add `File.WriteAllLines(filePath, result.Select(entry => $"{entry.Key} {entry.Value}"))`

Comment: Where do they say they want to write the result back to a file?

Comment: Nowhere and I'm maybe making a false assumption here but I'm not sure the OP will be able to use this result as is

Comment: @AnuViswan LINQ does not evaluate until you enumerate it. It does not loop the entire set for every call.

Comment: @AnuViswan more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=netframework-4.7.2